# Where do I get sports information for web app development?

Tags: php, content, web-applications

I'm creating an application for personal use and will be needing sports related information such as previews, scores, and recaps. My question is, how do I get said information? Are there syndication services? How do other sports apps on say android get this information? I would be running this in a php environment on my home web server and am fairly familiar with curl. I am however, open to other methods.

I'm looking for particular methods/services.

Answer (score 1):

I know recently, ESPN opened up their data for freemium. http://developer.espn.com/

If Bernie's or ESPN doesn't work for you, you could always look where other networks like Yahoo Fantasy Football get their stats. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Stats Inc.](http://www.stats.com/index.asp) is probably the biggest source of sports data.

Answer (score 0):

Travis Pflanz, your link is broken.

The one of the best sports data provider is OptaSports.com: http://optasports.com/

It is used at many sports projects. But it's quite expensive for personal usage.